# complex data as optional javascript function parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, parameters

I would like to write a javascript function that can accept a variable number of parameters, and these parameters should be something with a structure.
let's make an example:

the function will inject some HTML inside the page, and this HTML must repeat for each element passed to the function

let's assume this:

```
element1 = {name:"john",image:"/john.jpg"}
element2 = {name:"jack",image:"/jack01.jpg"}
element3 = {name:"Linda",image:"/001.jpg"}

option1 = [element1,element2]
option2 = [element1,element2,element3]

function injectPeople (opt){
  i=0
  foreach opt {
    inject opt[i].name;
    injectelsewhere opt[i].image
  i++
}

}
```

I would like to call the function as follow:

```
injectPeople (option1);
```

or

```
injectPeople (option2);
```

or else

```
injectPeople ();
```

wich will not inject enything.

is there a clean way to achieve this? are objects and arrays the best way?

PS : the title is a bit odd, but I haven't find any way to describe it better, feel free to edit it to make the question more clear.

Comment: It would probably be easiest to pass it as one array argument. Is that clean enough?

Comment: yes, you mean just not define the "elements"

Comment: Well, they would still need to be defined inside the array, obviously. I don't really see the issue here.

Comment: will all the element properties be accessible inside the array, may I do something like in the pseudocode: inject opt[i].name; ?

Comment: I can show you an example, hold on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
var elements = [{name:"john",image:"/john.jpg" },   
                {name:"jack",image:"/jack01.jpg"},
                {name:"Linda",image:"/001.jpg"}],
    option1 = elements.slice(1, elements.length),
    option2 = elements;

function injectPeople (opts){

    if(!opts) throw new ReferenceError('opts not defined');

    $.each(opts, function(i, v){
        //do inject stuff
        console.log(v.name, v.image);
    });    
}

injectPeople(option1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sWB64/

Answer (score 1):

In newer browsers, you could simply use [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```
option1.forEach(function (a){
    injectPeople(a);
})
```